# jquery returns two objects when only one exists

Tags: javascript, jquery

given this HTML,

```
<div id="dd_container" class="dd dd_container">
 <ul class="dd_deploy">
   <li class="dd_deploy">
     more options
   </li>
  </ul>
 <ul class="dd">
   <li class="dd">
     el1
   </li>
   <li class="dd">
     el2
   </li>
   <li class="dd">
     el3
   </li>   
 </ul>
</div>​
```

why does this jquery function print to the console two times?

```
$(document).on('click','.dd_deploy', function(){
    console.log($(this).parents('.dd_container').children('ul.dd'));
});​
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mBPfG/

Comment: It's rather uncommon to have nested elements with explicitly the same class. Do you have any special reason to do so?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Because you have 2 `.dd_deploy` elements, one nested inside the other so the event is bubbling.

```
<ul class="dd_deploy">
    <li class="dd_deploy">
        more options
    </li>
</ul>
```

If this HTML structure is intended, you can use `event.stopPropagation` to prevent the event bubbling, like this:

```
$(document).on('click','.dd_deploy', function(e){
    e.stopPropagation();
    console.log($(this).parents('.dd_container').children('ul.dd'));
});​
```

Note also that having `$(document)` as the primary selector on a delegated event handler is not the ideal for performance. Instead of `document` use the nearest element which is not appended to the DOM dynamically.

Comment: I think I'll go for `$(document).on('click','ul.dd_deploy', function(e){`. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

Because the event is bubbling through the `<li>` to the `<ul>`.

See my [modification](http://jsfiddle.net/mBPfG/):

```
$(document).on('click','.dd_deploy', function(event){
    console.log(event.target)
});​
```

It will print the `<li>` element, followed by the `<ul>` element.

To prevent this, you need your event handler to either `return false` or call `event.stopPropagation()`.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).on('click','.dd_deploy', function(e){
    e.stopPropagation(); //stops the bubbling
    console.log($(this).parents('.dd_container').children('ul.dd'));
});​
```

Comment: It's a fix to the problem, but doesn't really answer the question.

Comment: @Juhana what **doesn't** it answer?

Comment: "Why". You can read it between the lines if you know what "bubbling" is, but it's fair to assume a person who has to ask doesn't know about it.

Comment: Thanks for this. So my click actually hits the `<li>` element and then goes all the way up the document tree? Is there anyway besides `stopPropogation` to control how far it goes up? Or is that what `$(document).on` is for?

Comment: @thomas you can echo out `e.target` to see what element the event is currently on if you do not prevent bubbling.